# Why is there all these artifacts imported into libs-release folder after installing Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

After a fresh install of Artifactory, I've noticed a huge number of files I don't need in artifactory/libs-release dir. From Artifact Repository Browser, these artifacts are listed under the libs-release folder cf image below

Is it possible to install Artifactory without all these artifacts ?

Can I safely remove them ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not stored in your Artifactory instance. The repository libs-release is a virtual repository that contains both local and remote repositories. This will show an aggregate view of three things:

1. The items in the Artifactory local repositories (which are stored in your instance)
2. The items cached in your Artifactory remote repositories (which are stored in your instance)
3. The items available in the Artifactory remote repositories (but not stored in your instance)

In your case, the items you are seeing fall under #3 and are not actually stored in your Artifactory instance, as such you cannot delete them.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks !